# Is that possible delete 1 row in 2 tables sqlite

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sqlite

I have 3 tables : `contact` , `group` and `contactGroup`.

`contact` and `group` have their own IDs, and `contactGroup`  has id-contact and group-id

So i want to delete one id group and then if that id group deleted so contactGroup must be deleted also.

Is that possible on sqlite  ? And how to do that then ?

Comment: Sounds like you want a foreign key with a `ON DELETE CASCADE` rule. (Remember that foreign keys have to be explicitly turned on in sqlite)

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a foreign key in column ContactId in junction table contactGroup that references the id of the corresponding record in the Group table. By enabling option [ON DELETE CASCADE](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) in the declaration of the foreign key, you will get exactly the behavior that you expect : whenever a record is deleted in the Group table, the children records in contactGroup will automatically be deleted as well.

You likely want the same behavior on column ContactId in groupContact, that references the Contact table.

Example DDL :

```
CREATE TABLE track(
    GroupId      INTEGER, 
    ContactId   INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY(GroupId) REFERENCES Group(Id ) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(ContactId) REFERENCES Contact(Id ) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

);